# Curl responds with empty string. How to get more information?

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I'm getting a pretty weird behaviour and I have no idea how to get more information about what is going on...

I'm using `Paypal Express Checkout` with NVP API. Basically, I send a request and Paypal responds with `key1=value1&key2=value2...`

I send a first request with curl, everything goes fine.

Then I send the next request with curl, but the `$result` is empty. But what is weird is that if I print the `$paypal_url` and copy/paste it in a browser, I get the correct response.

So it seems that curl is not sending the request, but I don't get why. How can I spy the exchange between curl and Paypal ? Or how can I get more information on what's going on ?

Thanks !

```
//First request (fine) : Get Paypal Checkout Details
$paypal_url = $url."?VERSION=204.0&USER=".$user."&PWD=".$pwd."&SIGNATURE=".$signature."&METHOD=GetExpressCheckoutDetails&TOKEN=".$token;
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $paypal_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

//parse the result
parse_str($result);

//Check data integrity (nothing relevant)
if($ACK!="Success" || $token!=$TOKEN || $amount!=$PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT || $currency!=$PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE) {
    header("HTTP/1.0 402 Payment Required");
    die("Couldn't realize the payment checkout : ".$ACK."  ".$TOKEN."   required: ".$PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT."   ".$PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE."<br/>".$token."  payed : ".$amount."   ".$currency);
}

//Second request : Do Paypal checkout
$paypal_url = $url;
$paypal_url .= "?VERSION=204.0";
$paypal_url .= "&USER=".$user;
$paypal_url .= "&PWD=".$pwd;
$paypal_url .= "&SIGNATURE=".$signature;
$paypal_url .= "&METHOD=DoExpressCheckoutPayment";
$paypal_url .= "&TOKEN=".$token;
$paypal_url .= "&PAYERID=".$payerid;
$paypal_url .= "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale";
$paypal_url .= "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=".$amount;
$paypal_url .= "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=".$currency;
$paypal_url .= "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT =".$amount;

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $paypal_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

//Display the URL and the result... But the result is missing !
die($paypal_url."\n".$result);

//If I now copy/paste the content of $paypal_url into a browser, I get the expected result.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable verbose mode in CURL...

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
```

...and have a look at the data being transmitted/received

Comment: I just luckily solved my issue : there is a space before the equal in PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT =. I think that it made curl crash but not the browser. Anyway, my question was "how to get more details" and you perfectly answer that. Thanks !

Comment: right, CURL doesn't like blank spaces in the url, the text following that blank space get parsed as another command line parameter)